# CSS Blend Mode not working

Tags: html, css

I would like to play with the CSS blend mode property but it seems like nothing is happening when I apply the rules.

Am I doing something wrong? I have applied the isolation rule to the parent and the mix-blend-mode to the element I want to play with.

Here's the code and a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/xdbLjR).

```css
.day-old {
    position: relative;
    isolation: isolate;
}

.day-old:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 99.9%;
    height: 38px;
    content: "";
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: -1;
}

.day-old .day-row {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.day-row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.day {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    margin: 0;
}

.day span {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.availability {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
     margin: 0;
}

.slot {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: #3c763d;
    background: #dff0d8;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: -1px 0px 0px #c7d9b9 inset, 0px -1px 0px #c7d9b9 inset;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<div class="day-old">
    <div class="day-row">
     <p class="inner day"><span><strong>13/04</strong></span></p>
     <p class="availability">
       <span class="slot">
         <strong>2500</strong>                                              </span>
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve and what do you expect to happen? Maybe a screenshot?

Comment: It is working, you just need to use colors where difference will be more _visual_ ... try it on an image, or a multicolor background, which it's meant to be used on

Comment: @GurtejSingh nothing in particular, want to check if I can achieve a nice look with that property!

Comment: @LGSon I will try it! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code you have written **is working**, but the effects don't seem so obvious due to the color you have chosen. The mix-blend-mode property you have used achieves best results when used with a **background image**. **You can combine the background image and background color property**. An example would be:

```
<div class=”container”>
  <h1 class=”header-text”>Hello world</h1>
</div>

.container {
  background-image: url(‘image.png’);
  background-size: cover;
}

.header-text {
  font-size: 7rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: darkcyan;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

You can also check our an interesting article [here](https://kolosek.com/css-blend-mode/) that might help further explain the property.

Answer (score 1):

Blend modes are typically used with background images. The results are similar to the blend modes in Photoshop where you would have a layer with solid color over a photo layer, then change blend mode to something like 'screen' or 'darken' etc.

One example is:

```
.foo {
  background-image: url(trees.jpg);
  background-color: green;
  background-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to play with just colors, instead of mixing image+color